# Bootstrap popover won't work with a class but will work with id

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make the bootstrap popover plugin work on multiple elements that share the same class. For now it is the large grey block level 'more information' buttons. You can find the link
[here](http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/test2.html#)

Previously the popover worked when the it was a singular id like so `id="pop"` and the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#pop').popover()
});
```

However when I change the 2 buttons that say 'more information' `from id="pop"` to `class="pop"`and ammend the JavaScript accordingly the popover stops working on multiple buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.pop').popover()
});

<a class="btn btn-block pop" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="Popover on right">More Information</a></p>
```

Is it the case that the popover plugin will not work on multiple elements with the same class? There are no console errors if you look at the link I have provided.

Comment: Just tested it on your link and I get a popover on both "More Information" buttons. (Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57, OSX Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
$('.pop').popover({
    html: true,
    content:mycontent,
    trigger: 'manual'
}).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[just check my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/fsRaN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  options = {
   placement: 'top',
   trigger : 'click'
  }
  $('[rel="popover"]').popover(options);
});
```

In Html:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-block pop" rel="popover" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="Popover on right">More Information</a></p>

<p><a class="btn btn-block pop" rel="popover" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="Popover on right">More Information</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing which solved it for me was to add tabindex='0' if you intend to dismiss on next click and if you are using the <a> tag and not the <button> tag
Read more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#dismiss-on-next-click

Your markup would change to this

```
<a tabindex=0 class="btn btn-block pop" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="Popover on right">More Information</a></p>
```